# Ionic ViewChild (Tabs) not loading main page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Problem is the viewchild is not working as it is supposed to be, **BUT** when I remove the `viewchild` the page does work but I still need to type the page name so I need viewchild.

> My Ionic version **5.4.16**

**ERROR**

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.outlet is
>   undefined select@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:105637:33
>   ngOnInit@http://localhost:8100/tabs-tabs-module.js:132:19

EDIT: **tabs.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { TabsPageRoutingModule } from './tabs-routing.module';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

here is my **tabs.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonTabs } from '@ionic/angular'

@Component({
   selector: 'app-tabs',
   templateUrl: './tabs.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tabs.page.scss'],
    })
export class TabsPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('tabs', {static: true}) tabs:IonTabs

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.tabs.select('feed')
  }
}
```

My HTML **(tabs.page.html)**

```html
<ion-tabs #tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="feed">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Feed</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="uploader">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Upload</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="profile">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

My **tabs-routing-moudule.ts**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
          {path: 'feed', loadChildren: '../feed/feed.module#FeedPageModule'},
          {path: 'uploader', loadChildren: '../uploader/uploader.module#UploaderPageModule'},
          {path: 'profile', loadChildren: '../profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'}
        ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

If this would help, I'll also include my app.routing.module.ts

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'tabs', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)},
      {
        path: 'register',
        loadChildren: () => import('./register/register.module').then( m => m.RegisterPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
      },
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
      ],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: can you explain better? 
What do you mean by 'viewchild' doesn't work as it should?

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez - hello, okay.. viewchild exists on my `tab.page.ts` I need it so when I go to my `localhost:8100` then the first tab which is `feed` should be loaded. but then I got an error `ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.outlet is undefined
select@http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:105637:33
ngOnInit@http://localhost:8100/tabs-tabs-module.js:132:19` Ihaven't included the error on my question. sorry need to update it

Comment: can you show me the code of tabs-tabs-module.js pelase?

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez sure please see the edit code above, P.S just included all my tabs folder files there. thank you

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez - Hi, to clarify, tabs-tabs-module.js pertains to the tabs link.. which you can see above.

Comment: i don't understand you, the error was in tabs-tabs-module.js:132:19 line 132, could u show me that code?

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez - it's in this page i guess `tabs-routing-moudule.ts` or in this page `tabs.page.ts` you can see it above, there is no .js file name in ionic/angular .. there are `ts` file extensions.

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez - but my main problem is that I cannot load my main page. there are erros. even switching tabs I cannot load it

Comment: I'm sorry, but with so little information I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Add the block of code

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.tabs.select('feed')
  }
```

into your `tabs.module.ts` NOT `tabs.page.ts`.